# Should /boot/efi be mounted?

Tags: mount, uefi, gpt

Ubuntu is on a GPT disk. At some stage in the past I needed access to the efi partition. I notice that it's mounted at /boot/efi.

My question is for people who are using UEFI disks and not MBR (MBR disks won't have this mounted as the partition does not exist), can you please look at your Ubuntu installs and check /boot/efi is mounted by default? And let me know.

I can't remember if I mounted this or not, have a feeling I should dismount this. I'm worried if I dismount there may be issues..

Many Thanks

Comment: You just have to check your fstab: `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: That shows /boot/efi is mounted. That isn't my question however - thx.

Comment: Mine is mounted, and have never used/checked it.  I would not unmount it.  If not broken, don't break it.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand you, but you ask "can you please look at your Ubuntu installs and check /boot/efi is mounted by default?". The fstab answers this question.

Comment: I believe the mount is required when grub, or kernel are updated. It may only be required on a reinstall of grub or major grub update. While you should not normally install in UEFI mode to MBR drives, you can and then it still has a ESP. And if BIOS booting from gpt, then you have to have a bios_grub partition. Your fstab will tell you what you mount on reboot. But `sudo mount` will tell you what you currently have mounted.

Comment: It is mounted at boot to load the OS, if I have that right.  It is probably not needed to be mounted after, but certain updates might need it mounted.  Does not hurt anything by leaving it mounted, but might break updates if unmounted.

Comment: If you ever go through the instructions for an Arch install you will find you have to have this mounted for kernel updates to work. That suggests to me that the comments from others apply equally to Ubuntu